# how to check the speed of processor in windows xp

Tags: windows-xp

when i right click on my computer ,in properties it shows 
Intel(R) Pentium(R) M processor 2.26GHz and also 279MHZ .so there are two speeds listed .
but when i see using directx it shows only Intel(R) Pentium(R) M processor 2.26GHz 
when i see using msinfo32 it shows 798MHZ .
in device manager it shows Intel(R) Pentium(R) M processor 2.26GHz .so how these speeds are displayed .

In CPU-Z it is showing:
Name:Intel Pentinum M 780
Specification:Intel(R) Pentium(R) M processor 2.26GHz
core Speed:798 MHZ

and another important thing is that when i view the system information on right clicking  my computer it shows Intel(R) Pentium(R) M processor 2.26GHz,how this speed getting displayed ,is this the speed provided by manufacturer .and how the another speed 279MHZ is displaying.

Does windows displays the incorrect speed .because it is displaying the speeds does not match .

Comment: Please can you add tags etc. and clarify your question to indicate what programming language etc. you wish this information for?

Comment: not specific to any programming language , just to clarify with the processor speed

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to retrieve the processor speed. Lately most processors use variable speeds to safe lots of energy while running. This is especially true on laptops in low power mode.

Sometimes multipe core speeds get added together so it shows extremely high speeds.

Easily copied from another question:

```
using System.Management;

public uint CPUSpeed()
{
  ManagementObject Mo = new ManagementObject("Win32_Processor.DeviceID='CPU0'");
  uint sp = (uint)(Mo["CurrentClockSpeed"]);
  Mo.Dispose();
  return sp;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: `using(ManagementObject Mo = new ManagementObject("Win32_Processor.DeviceID='CPU0'")){ //do stuff }` removes need for the `Mo.Dispose()` (which is easily forgotten).

Comment: ok,i got that i want to know that when i view the speed by right clicking on my computer.Intel(R) Pentium(R) M processor 2.26GHz.how windows is displaying this speed ,where does it come .is this the one provided by the processor manufacturer,is that the complete line is string.

Comment: i got the answer,i installed intel processor identification utility .it says that expected speed is 2.26hz and reported is 0.79ghz .and the first the "Intel pentinum processor 2.26GHZ" is specification of processor provided by the manufacturer.

Comment: So, I think "Intel Pentinum M 780 Specification:Intel(R) Pentium(R) M processor 2.26GHz" is string .